# Difference between mouseListener and mouseMotionListener in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, mouse

Is mouseMotionListener going to trigger an event once the mouse moves over the component, whereas mouseListener only triggers if I press a button?

So if I have only a mousePressed event, then I don't need a mouseMotionListener? Only if I had a mouseEntered or mouseExited?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. `mouseMotionListener` is used to perform actions when your mouse moves over a "hotspot"

Good example can be found [here](http://www.realapplets.com/tutorial/MouseMotionExample.html)

When dealing with `mousePressed` events, you only need `mousePressed` events unless you wanted to add more events to perform while the mouse is hovered.

Answer (score 5):

They listen for different events:

[MouseListener](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

```
mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)   // Called just after the user clicks the listened-to component.
mouseEntered(MouseEvent event)   // Called just after the cursor enters the bounds of the listened-to component.
mouseExited(MouseEvent event)    // Called just after the cursor exits the bounds of the listened-to component.
mousePressed(MouseEvent event)   // Called just after the user presses a mouse button while the cursor is over the listened-to component.
mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)  // Called just after the user releases a mouse button after a mouse press over the listened-to component
```

[MouseMotionListener](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)

```
mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)   // Called in response to the user moving the mouse while holding a mouse button down. This event is fired by the component that fired the most recent mouse-pressed event, even if the cursor is no longer over that component.
mouseMoved(MouseEvent event)     // Called in response to the user moving the mouse with no mouse buttons pressed. This event is fired by the component that's currently under the cursor.
```

Add the listeners according to what event you're after.